# What component should I use to display enabled/disabled state?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have been wondering what component I should use to display state of enabled/disabled behaviours in WinForms.

For example I have function that returns state of 2 different processes.
And I want to display like green and red color on GUI, so that user could easily know which process has wich state.

In Java I have used `ProgressBar`, like setting it to 100 and 0, so it represents the state of that process. But as for now, I have moved to C#, so I would like to know what components you use for this purpose, maybe there is something better to use.

Comment: Depends on the requirement and taste of end user. Many times only showing text "Running" is sufficient. Further you can use any image, and many controls to achieve this.

Comment: You can use a `ProgressBar` in C# too, but if you only need a dashboard red/green light type of thing, then perhaps use an `Image` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any component with a background color property will do. I suggest you use `Panel` and switch the background color according to your state.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the technology, but CheckBox is one option in both WinForms and WPF. Plus you can use Label too (with BackColor / Background properties). Finally if you want to go fancy, you can use animations in WPF.

Comment: My bad, but i aim at WFA (Windows Form Application) if i am correct.

Comment: That acronym is unheard of. The standard term is WinForms for that thing.

Comment: I just picked it from VS 2012. Atleast it shows me WFA :)

Comment: Also we already have a bunch of W?? technologies around (WPF, WCF, WF, WP, WMI to name just a few). People won't want to add more to that list. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a `Panel` and change its background color or (more intuitively) a read-only `CheckBox`.

A progress bar is not really a good choice, unless you put it in "marquee" state when something is *currently active* and hide it when it is not. Otherwise a progress bar is meant to display ... well ... progress.

So this comes down to:

If you want to show that some process is activated/deactivated, for example by some sort of configuration, or simply "not performing a task right now", I'd use either a `Panel` with a background color or a `CheckBox`.

If you want to show that some process is currently working (without knowing the exact progress), I'd use a `ProgressBack` with a "marquee" state (also called "indeterminate").

Comment: Yep, that's why i am asking this question, because i also think that ProgressBar is not a good choice i had made.

Comment: @arccuks I modified my answer to make clearer in which situation I'd use what.

Comment: Much clearer to me now, ty.